# Kohana 3.2 set router for a controller which has a prefix URI belongs to another controller

Tags: controller, kohana, router, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

I have 2 controllers account.php and address.php in the same directory APP/controller. For the first controller account.php, I use default router for URI like: account/create, account/login, account/logout... When writing second controller, I want to use all URI of address.php start with account/address/. As you can see here, I'm taking the same URI router matches with account controller.

My first approach:

```
// Add new address
Route::set('address', 'account/address/<action>')
        ->defaults(array(
                'controller' => 'address',
                'action'     => 'index',
        ));
```

My address controller

```
public function before()
{
    parent::before();

    if ( ! Auth::instance()->logged_in())
    {
        // Redirect to a login page (or somewhere else).
        $this->request->redirect('');
    }
}



// nothing here
public function action_index()
{
    $this->request->redirect('');
}


// create account
public function action_create()
{

    // Create an instance of a model
    $profile = new Model_Address();

    // received the POST
    if (isset($_POST) && Valid::not_empty($_POST)) 
    {   

        // // validate the form
        $post = Validation::factory($_POST)
        ->rule('firstname', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('lastname', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('address', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('phone', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('city', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('state', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('zip', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('country', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('primary_email_address', 'email');

        // if the form is valid and the username and password matches
        if ($post->check()) 
        {

            if($profile->create_profile($_POST)) 
            {
                $sent = kohana::message('profile', 'profile_created');
            }

        } else {
            // validation failed, collect the errors
            $errors = $post->errors('address');
        }

    }

    // display
    $this->template->title = 'Create new address';
    $this->template->content = View::factory('address/create')
            ->bind('post', $post)
            ->bind('errors', $errors)
            ->bind('sent', $sent);
}
```

It seems to be ok, but the router account/address/create is not working. Kohana throws 404 message for that URI.

Anyone knows why it happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked your route on my system and it works fine, so I assume the error is somewhere else.
Check if your controller class name is `Controller_Address`, also try to place this route as the first one in the bootstrap, as the [docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing) say:

> it is important to understand that routes are matched in the order
>   they are added, and as soon as a URL matches a route, routing is
>   essentially "stopped" and the remaining routes are never tried.
>   Because the default route matches almost anything, including an empty
>   url, new routes must be place before it.

Another thing, not related to the question - you really should place validation inside your model. The controller is not the place for it ;)

Comment: Awesome man, putting it in first priority does the trick. And yes, you are right, validation should be in model instead, it will make our controller looks clean and readable.